# vertex video action recognition - predict timeframes instead of frames

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Trying to train Vertex to identify actions. My problem is, whenever I run a prediction, I only get in response a single timeframe, e.g.

```
{
   "id":"4286686324175405056",
   "displayName":"SITTING",
   "timeSegmentStart":"288s",
   "timeSegmentEnd":"288s",
   "confidence":0.99240303
}
```

while I was trying to train the modeal that `SITTING` starts when the person is **standing** near a chair, and ends when they're sitted. Looks like Vertex knows only to identify the final "sitted" situation and not the length of the action itself (standing, banding, sitting) I would expect to get a `timeSegmentStart` different than `timeSegmentEnd` but I always get them identical

Comment: Hi @shaharsol, timeSegmentStart is the start timestamp in the video to do prediction on and timeSegmentEnd is the start timestamp in the video to do prediction on as given in this [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/migration/UJ14%20Vertex%20SDK%20AutoML%20Video%20Classification.ipynb). The values indicate the start and end of the prediction. The time difference between timeSegmentStart and timeSegmentEnd shows the time taken for completing the task.Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar and thanks for replying. I still don't understand why I need to timeSegmentStart/timeSegmentEnd when I annotate actions. What contains the label is the annotation using annotationSegmentStart/annotationSegmentEnd, so what's the deal with the labeless timeSegmentation? Anyway, my main goal is for the prediction engine to return segment values rather than action timestamps. i.e. if i tag basketball dunks, i want to know it occurred between 1:32-1:36 and not that there was a timestamp 1:34 around which the action took place. how do i tell the prediction engine that?

Comment: Hi @shaharsol, can you provide the sample code which you have tried?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar i was using the console GUI to run a batch prediction, no code involved....

Comment: Hi @shaharsol, for your requirement, I would suggest you to use a [client library](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/introduction-unified-platform#cloud_client_libraries) using which you would be able work with service metaphors. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar thanks for your suggestion but how would that help? isn't the client library just a connivence to use the API not directly via http/REST?

Comment: Hi @shaharsol, Yes it is. Since this feature is currently not available in Vertex AI. If you want this feature in Vertex AI, you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).